# NotePad++ RegEx for pulling text between two tags?

Tags: regex, notepad++

Fellow Forum Members,
Can someone please help develop a RegEx that is able to search for text that resides within an opening and closing tag? The example below illustrates it better. "para" is in the closing and opening tag and the data I need to pull is in between these two tags.

`<para>Text I would like to see in the NotePad++ Search Result Hit List</para>`

What RegEx can perform such as task?  Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have notepad++ installed but you can try: `<para>(.*?)</para>`

Answer (score 5):

Try this expression:

```
(?<=<para>)[\s\S]*?(?=<\/para>)
```

Comment: `[^\S\s]` won't match anything.